# using XSL to count elements

Tags: xml, xslt

**2021-12-30 UPDATE:**

OMG - it took me two months, including countless hours reading, experimenting, and testing - but I've finally constructed a query that gets the results I was looking for:

> The answers I'm *expecting* to get in the `count` column
> should be `3`, `1`, `0`, and `3`

Excerpt from my original XSL:

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::dict/
                    key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                    following-sibling::dict/key)" /></td>
```

My newly working modification:

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::dict[1]/
                    key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                    following-sibling::dict/key)" /></td>
```

I still don't understand why this three character addition is necessary, so my second question still stands:

> Why is it that the `following-sibling` key word that I'm
> using is finding not only siblings (nodes having the same parent
> node), but also "cousins" (nodes at the same level, regardless of
> which node is the parent)?

However, given how much time and effort I've wasted in trying to understand this, I'm at the point of no longer caring why the code works, as long as it works.  You can consider this question **closed**.

**2021-10-25 UPDATE:**

After spending too much spare time reading everything I could find on the Internet that seems relevant, plus downloading and playing with several XML tools, I'm still confused - mainly because the XQuery expression that's giving me these bizarre answers is not much different from the other ones that are giving me the results I expect.

I'm going to try to explain my logic in constructing the "count()" expression in my Sample-Code.xsl file; I would appreciate having the flaws in this logic pointed out to me.  (Apologies for the long lines below; it was the easiest way I could think of to illustrate my thought process.)

First off, I'm iterating over "plist/dict/key", which should (and, apparently, does) trigger four times for the Sample-Input.xml:  on encountering "Entry1", "second entry", "another main entry", and "final sample".  Now, for the moment, concentrating on "Entry1" and ignoring what it'll find on subsequent passes*, I output "value-of select='.'" ("Entry1") to the first column of the HTML table, and then ...

```
    <!-- attempt to calculate a count, ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                                                                                  )" />
    <!-- (working backwards thru the expression), specifically of "key"s ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                                                                               key)" />
    <!-- that are children of "dict"s, ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                                                                          dict/key)" />
    <!-- that have a "following-sibling" relationship ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                                                       following-sibling::dict/key)" />
    <!-- to some (parent level) "key" ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                                                   key/following-sibling::dict/key)" />
    <!-- having "EntryCollectionB" as its "text()" ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                        key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/following-sibling::dict/key)" />
    <!-- that is a child of a "dict" ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(                   dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/following-sibling::dict/key)" />
    <!-- that is a "following-sibling" ... -->
<xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/following-sibling::dict/key)" />
    <!-- of the "plist/dict/key" that's currently being worked on - "Entry1". -->
```

* Or maybe I shouldn't be ignoring that?  Or I should write something else into the expression to insure that it does ignore that?

Where else am I going wrong?

**2021-10-03 UPDATE:**

Okay, it took me a while, but I've created sample files by editing down one of the XML files I'm trying to work on, removing all the confidential data but leaving the structure intact.

Sample-Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Entry1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ECA Identifier</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECADetail1</key>
                <string>The quick brown fox</string>
                <key>ECADetail2</key>
                <integer>1112</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Identifier for the first ECB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail1</key>
                <false/>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>EBC2's name</key>
                    <string>jumps over the lazy dog.</string>
                </dict>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail3</key>
                <string>three</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail4</key>
                <string>four</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail5</key>
                <string>five</string>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToMe</key>
                <data>
                yadda+yadda+yadda/yadda+yaddayaddayaddayadda
                </data>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToo</key>
                <integer>987654321</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>second ECB for Entry1 has a different title</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail1</key>
                <false/>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>a name for Ecb2 goes here</key>
                    <string>vaults above the recalcitrant canine.</string>
                </dict>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail3</key>
                <string>is the number of the count,</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail4</key>
                <string>and what the number of the count shall be</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail5</key>
                <string>is right out.</string>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToMe</key>
                <data>
                MORE/inde+cipher+able/and+IRReleVaNTinbase64
                </data>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToo</key>
                <integer>19283746</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Entry1 third ECB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail1</key>
                <true/>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Ecb3 has a name</key>
                    <string>is intimidated by the sleeping dragon.</string>
                </dict>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail3</key>
                <string>is a magic number</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail4</key>
                <string>is the legs in a zoo</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail5</key>
                <string>ready or not, here I come!</string>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToMe</key>
                <data>
                WiLlY0USt1lLFe3dMe/WhEnImSiXtYfOuR/60plUsF0R
                </data>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToo</key>
                <integer>6406406566</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>what this data pertains to</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>reference code</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>one,two</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>999</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>eeny</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>more characters</string>
        <key>bitObuckets</key>
        <string>textity textext</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>66645714</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>765432109</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>828474104</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>second entry</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>5564738291</key>
            <dict>
                <key>wardrobe</key>
                <string>lionWitch</string>
                <key>buuleeun</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>2's ECB name</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>sequence identifier</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>three,four</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>thuh-ree</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>841391812</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>another collection of data</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>identifier string</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>buckle my shoe</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>again</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>meeny</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>say what you want</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>51736576</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>456789012</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>841391812</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>another main entry</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>5564738291</key>
            <dict>
                <key>wardrobe</key>
                <string>lionWitch</string>
                <key>buuleeun</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>my third data set</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>ID code</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>five,six</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>tenAgain</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>miney</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>more to say</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>1576960</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>1248163264</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>842184218</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>final sample</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>5564738291</key>
            <dict>
                <key>wardrobe</key>
                <string>lionWitch</string>
                <key>buuleeun</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ECB (but for #4?)</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>name, of sorts</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>nine,ten</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>tenAgain</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>84218421</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>four's second ECB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>three is also 7?</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>eight is also four</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>cra-zee</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>474828131</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>369,121518</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>code name for this item</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>close the door</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>heaven</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>963852741</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>and here's another group of data</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>code name for this item</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>do it again</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>heaven</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>moe</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>piece of text</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>19189760</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>567890123</integer>
        <key>supportedDeviceTypes</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>303030303</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sample-Code.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Heading and preliminary stuff</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#336699">Main</th>
      <th>count</th>
      <th bgcolor="#3366cc">EntryCollectionB</th>
      <th bgcolor="#339966">EntryCollectionB/<br/>
        ECBImportantDetail3</th>
      <th bgcolor="#3399cc">EntryCollectionB/<br/>
        ECBImportantDetail4</th>
      <th bgcolor="#33cc66">EntryCollectionB/<br/>
        ECBImportantDetail5</th>
      <th bgcolor="#33cc99">ImportantDatum6</th>
      <th bgcolor="#663399">ImportantDatum7</th>
      <th bgcolor="#6633cc">ImportantDatum8</th>
      <th bgcolor="#669933">iDo-aboutThisOne</th>
      <th bgcolor="#6699cc">ANDagain</th>
      <th bgcolor="#66cc33">amount</th>
    </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/key">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#66cc99"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key)" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#993366"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#9933cc"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key/
                        following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ECBImportantDetail3']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#996633"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key/
                        following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ECBImportantDetail4']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#9966cc"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key/
                        following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ECBImportantDetail5']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99cc33"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ImportantDatum6']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99cc66"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ImportantDatum7']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc3366"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ImportantDatum8']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc3399"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='iDo-aboutThisOne']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc6633"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ANDagain']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc6699"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='amount']/
                        following-sibling::integer" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample-Output.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <body>
      <h2>Heading and preliminary stuff</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#336699">Main</th>
            <th>count</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3366cc">EntryCollectionB</th>
            <th bgcolor="#339966">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail3</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3399cc">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail4</th>
            <th bgcolor="#33cc66">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail5</th>
            <th bgcolor="#33cc99">ImportantDatum6</th>
            <th bgcolor="#663399">ImportantDatum7</th>
            <th bgcolor="#6633cc">ImportantDatum8</th>
            <th bgcolor="#669933">iDo-aboutThisOne</th>
            <th bgcolor="#6699cc">ANDagain</th>
            <th bgcolor="#66cc33">amount</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">Entry1</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">Identifier for the first ECB</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc">three</td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633">four</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc">five</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">what this data pertains to</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">reference code</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">one,two</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">999</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">eeny</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">66645714</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">second entry</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">2's ECB name</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">another collection of data</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">identifier string</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">buckle my shoe</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">again</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">meeny</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">51736576</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">another main entry</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">ECB (but for #4?)</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">my third data set</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">ID code</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">five,six</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">tenAgain</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">miney</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">1576960</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">final sample</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">ECB (but for #4?)</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">and here's another group of data</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">code name for this item</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">do it again</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">heaven</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">moe</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">19189760</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

(I know I have more problems with this code than just the one I asked about here, but I have a feeling that once I understand what I'm doing wrong with this problem, the other pieces will fall into place.)

The answers I'm *expecting* to get in the `count` column should be `3`, `1`, `0`, and `3`; but it seems to be counting not just descendants, but all the matching data points from the current position to the end - and recounting them every time the position changes.

Any and all assistance will be appreciated.

**ORIGINAL MESSAGE:**

(Newless cluebie here - please be gentle.)

I recently got interested in XSL to modify some XML documents (eliminating irrelevant data, rearranging, formatting, etc.), but I've run into a problem that the many Web tutorials I've seen don't cover.  The closest I've found is at `http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/XML/0100__XSLT-stylesheet/Countnode.htm`, but this one still isn't counting the things I want to count.  Using the `Data.xml` given at that link, how do I go about e.g. counting how many `profession`s each `person` has?

Comment: Please don't put links to you documents: paste the sources in your question.

Comment: "I've run into a problem that the many Web tutorials I've seen don't cover". So your strategy for learning the language is wrong. Looking for examples that do exactly what you want is not a good approach to learning. You need to study the concepts and the primitive building blocks, so that you can assemble them in any way you choose to tackle problems that didn't occur to the tutorial writers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xsl:template match="person">
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="count(profession)"/>:
    ...
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did not follow your question (a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful) but I think I can answer this:

> still don't understand why this three character addition is necessary

- This expression:

  ```
  following-sibling::item/child
  ```

  selects the children of all following siblings;
- This expression:

  ```
  following-sibling::item[1]/child
  ```

  selects the children of the immediately following sibling only.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <child>11</child>
        <child>12</child>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <child>21</child>
        <child>22</child>
    </item>
    <item id="3">
        <child>31</child>
        <child>32</child>
    </item>
    <item id="4">
        <child>41</child>
        <child>42</child>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <test1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="item[@id='1']/following-sibling::item/child"/>
        </test1>
        <test2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="item[@id='1']/following-sibling::item[1]/child"/>
        </test2>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <test1>
    <child>21</child>
    <child>22</child>
    <child>31</child>
    <child>32</child>
    <child>41</child>
    <child>42</child>
  </test1>
  <test2>
    <child>21</child>
    <child>22</child>
  </test2>
</results>
```