# using XSL to sort elements

Tags: xml, xslt

(This is a follow-up to [my previous XSL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69387176/using-xsl-to-count-elements), using the same sample data that I posted there.  I'm posting the sample data again here, because I got scolded for just posting links the first time.)

Sample-Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Entry1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ECA Identifier</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECADetail1</key>
                <string>The quick brown fox</string>
                <key>ECADetail2</key>
                <integer>1112</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Identifier for the first ECB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail1</key>
                <false/>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>EBC2's name</key>
                    <string>jumps over the lazy dog.</string>
                </dict>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail3</key>
                <string>three</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail4</key>
                <string>four</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail5</key>
                <string>five</string>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToMe</key>
                <data>
                yadda+yadda+yadda/yadda+yaddayaddayaddayadda
                </data>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToo</key>
                <integer>987654321</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>second ECB for Entry1 has a different title</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail1</key>
                <false/>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>a name for Ecb2 goes here</key>
                    <string>vaults above the recalcitrant canine.</string>
                </dict>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail3</key>
                <string>is the number of the count,</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail4</key>
                <string>and what the number of the count shall be</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail5</key>
                <string>is right out.</string>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToMe</key>
                <data>
                MORE/inde+cipher+able/and+IRReleVaNTinbase64
                </data>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToo</key>
                <integer>19283746</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>Entry1 third ECB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail1</key>
                <true/>
                <key>ECBMinorDetail2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Ecb3 has a name</key>
                    <string>is intimidated by the sleeping dragon.</string>
                </dict>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail3</key>
                <string>is a magic number</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail4</key>
                <string>is the legs in a zoo</string>
                <key>ECBImportantDetail5</key>
                <string>ready or not, here I come!</string>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToMe</key>
                <data>
                WiLlY0USt1lLFe3dMe/WhEnImSiXtYfOuR/60plUsF0R
                </data>
                <key>ECBIrrelevantToo</key>
                <integer>6406406566</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>what this data pertains to</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>reference code</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>one,two</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>999</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>eeny</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>more characters</string>
        <key>bitObuckets</key>
        <string>textity textext</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>66645714</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>765432109</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>828474104</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>second entry</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>5564738291</key>
            <dict>
                <key>wardrobe</key>
                <string>lionWitch</string>
                <key>buuleeun</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>2's ECB name</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>sequence identifier</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>three,four</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>thuh-ree</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>841391812</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>another collection of data</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>identifier string</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>buckle my shoe</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>again</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>meeny</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>say what you want</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>51736576</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>456789012</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>841391812</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>another main entry</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>5564738291</key>
            <dict>
                <key>wardrobe</key>
                <string>lionWitch</string>
                <key>buuleeun</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>my third data set</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>ID code</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>five,six</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>tenAgain</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>miney</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>more to say</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>1576960</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>1248163264</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>842184218</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>final sample</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>5564738291</key>
            <dict>
                <key>wardrobe</key>
                <string>lionWitch</string>
                <key>buuleeun</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>EntryCollectionB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ECB (but for #4?)</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>name, of sorts</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>nine,ten</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>tenAgain</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>84218421</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>four's second ECB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>three is also 7?</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>eight is also four</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>cra-zee</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>474828131</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>369,121518</key>
            <dict>
                <key>tuuleeun</key>
                <false/>
                <key>batchCodes</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>5564738291</key>
                    <data>
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </data>
                </dict>
                <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
                <string>code name for this item</string>
                <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
                <string>close the door</string>
                <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
                <string>heaven</string>
                <key>moreSillyData</key>
                <data>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </data>
                <key>subcode</key>
                <integer>963852741</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>ImportantDatum6</key>
        <string>and here's another group of data</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum7</key>
        <string>code name for this item</string>
        <key>ImportantDatum8</key>
        <string>do it again</string>
        <key>whoCares</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>iDo-aboutThisOne</key>
        <string>heaven</string>
        <key>ANDagain</key>
        <string>moe</string>
        <key>moreSillyData</key>
        <data>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </data>
        <key>bucketObits</key>
        <string>piece of text</string>
        <key>amount</key>
        <integer>19189760</integer>
        <key>code</key>
        <integer>567890123</integer>
        <key>supportedDeviceTypes</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
        <key>subcode</key>
        <integer>303030303</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sample-Code.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Heading and preliminary stuff</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#336699">Main</th>
      <th>count</th>
      <th bgcolor="#3366cc">EntryCollectionB</th>
      <th bgcolor="#339966">EntryCollectionB/<br/>
        ECBImportantDetail3</th>
      <th bgcolor="#3399cc">EntryCollectionB/<br/>
        ECBImportantDetail4</th>
      <th bgcolor="#33cc66">EntryCollectionB/<br/>
        ECBImportantDetail5</th>
      <th bgcolor="#33cc99">ImportantDatum6</th>
      <th bgcolor="#663399">ImportantDatum7</th>
      <th bgcolor="#6633cc">ImportantDatum8</th>
      <th bgcolor="#669933">iDo-aboutThisOne</th>
      <th bgcolor="#6699cc">ANDagain</th>
      <th bgcolor="#66cc33">amount</th>
    </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/key">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#66cc99"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key)" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#993366"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#9933cc"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key/
                        following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ECBImportantDetail3']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#996633"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key/
                        following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ECBImportantDetail4']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#9966cc"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='EntryCollectionB']/
                        following-sibling::dict/key/
                        following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ECBImportantDetail5']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99cc33"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ImportantDatum6']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99cc66"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ImportantDatum7']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc3366"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ImportantDatum8']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc3399"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='iDo-aboutThisOne']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc6633"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='ANDagain']/
                        following-sibling::string" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#cc6699"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dict/key[text()='amount']/
                        following-sibling::integer" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample-Output.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <body>
      <h2>Heading and preliminary stuff</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#336699">Main</th>
            <th>count</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3366cc">EntryCollectionB</th>
            <th bgcolor="#339966">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail3</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3399cc">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail4</th>
            <th bgcolor="#33cc66">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail5</th>
            <th bgcolor="#33cc99">ImportantDatum6</th>
            <th bgcolor="#663399">ImportantDatum7</th>
            <th bgcolor="#6633cc">ImportantDatum8</th>
            <th bgcolor="#669933">iDo-aboutThisOne</th>
            <th bgcolor="#6699cc">ANDagain</th>
            <th bgcolor="#66cc33">amount</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">Entry1</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">Identifier for the first ECB</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc">three</td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633">four</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc">five</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">what this data pertains to</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">reference code</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">one,two</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">999</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">eeny</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">66645714</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">second entry</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">2's ECB name</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">another collection of data</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">identifier string</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">buckle my shoe</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">again</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">meeny</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">51736576</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">another main entry</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">ECB (but for #4?)</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">my third data set</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">ID code</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">five,six</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">tenAgain</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">miney</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">1576960</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">final sample</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">ECB (but for #4?)</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">and here's another group of data</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">code name for this item</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">do it again</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">heaven</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">moe</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">19189760</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Desired-Output.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <body>
      <h2>Heading and preliminary stuff</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#336699">Main</th>
            <th>count</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3366cc">EntryCollectionB</th>
            <th bgcolor="#339966">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail3</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3399cc">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail4</th>
            <th bgcolor="#33cc66">EntryCollectionB/<br>
               ECBImportantDetail5</th>
            <th bgcolor="#33cc99">ImportantDatum6</th>
            <th bgcolor="#663399">ImportantDatum7</th>
            <th bgcolor="#6633cc">ImportantDatum8</th>
            <th bgcolor="#669933">iDo-aboutThisOne</th>
            <th bgcolor="#6699cc">ANDagain</th>
            <th bgcolor="#66cc33">amount</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">another main entry</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">ECB (but for #4?)</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">my third data set</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">ID code</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">five,six</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">tenAgain</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">miney</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">1576960</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">Entry1</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">Identifier for the first ECB</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc">three</td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633">four</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc">five</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">what this data pertains to</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">reference code</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">one,two</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">999</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">eeny</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">66645714</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">final sample</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">ECB (but for #4?)</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">and here's another group of data</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">code name for this item</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">do it again</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">heaven</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">moe</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">19189760</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#66cc99">second entry</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td bgcolor="#993366">2's ECB name</td>
            <td bgcolor="#9933cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#996633"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#9966cc"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc33">another collection of data</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99cc66">identifier string</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3366">buckle my shoe</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc3399">again</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6633">meeny</td>
            <td bgcolor="#cc6699">51736576</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

The people providing the data I'm working with have now decided not to sort the data file, so I have to do it myself.  Adding `<xsl:sort select="plist/dict/key">` or `<xsl:sort select=".">` after
the `<xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/key">` doesn't work, and VS Code is only telling me there's an "XSLT compile error", but not telling what that error is.  Does anyone know what the problem with this could be?  Or, is there a way to get more info about this out of VSC?

Comment: You definitely need to find a development environment that gives you better diagnostics. Focus on getting your tooling into shape before you do any more debugging. I don't know VSCode so I don't know if the problem is fixable there, but I would suspect that it is.

Comment: If you have an unexplained error in your source code that you want help with, it would be good to actually include that version of your source code in your question.

Comment: The code you have posted here does not include an `xsl:sort` instruction and does not produce any errors. So the problem cannot be reproduced from your code and any answer given will be a mere guess. Please read this link very carefully: [mcve] and pay attention to both "reproducible" and "minimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to sort by the value of the `key` element you are correct to use the expression `.` on the `xsl:sort` element, because it's evaluated relative to each result of the `select` expression on the parent `for-each`.

I suspect your error is that you say you have:

```xml
<xsl:sort select=".">
```

... instead of:

```xml
<xsl:sort select="."/>
```

(Note the slash at the end of the element)

Comment: OMG, I don't believe I could have been so stupid!  Thank you, and thank you also for not rubbing it in. :-)